# Plane wave vs radial wave

Tags: waves

How does one distinguish a plane wave from a radial wave in the context of Young's double slit experiment with light?

Please help!

Comment: For spherical waves one uses the formalism of Fresnel diffraction.

Answer (score 1):

A plane wave has wave fronts that are planes.  A radial (spherical) wave has wave fronts that are spheres.

If the center of the sphere is located on a line perpendicular to the plane containing the slits, and which intersects the plane directly between the slits, the waves going through the slits will have the same phase. Then assuming the slits are small enough, it would not be possible to distinguish the radial wave from a plane wave which is parallel to the slit plane.

Answer (score 0):

Plain wave is just an approximation of the radial one for $r \rightarrow \infty$. So, given that you are looking far away from the source, every radial wave looks like a plane wave.